# Group and Compare multiple dataframe columns with conditions in Python

Tags: python, analytics

I'm tryng to print out the states with highest population in each region.

**Code Sample**:

```
# all unique regions
region_unique = data['Region'].unique()

# highest population
max_pop = data['population'].max()
```

How can I chain the above lines of code and bring in the `'States'` column to achieve my result?

**Dataset**:

[image]

Comment: `data.groupby(["States","Region"]).Population.max()` can you try this? or it could be the inverse, `data.groupby(["Region","States"]).Population.max()`

Comment: Thanks.
Though this doesn't answer my question correclty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you haven't mentioned any library...

You could first create a helper *dict*, mapping each region to an array of states. Each state is a tuple: `(state, pop)` (name and population count):

```
regions = {}
for state, pop, region in zip(data['States'], data['population'], data['Region']):
    res.setdefault(region, []).append((state, pop))
```

Then for each region you can pull out the most inhabited state:

```
for region, states in regions.items():
    print(region, max(states, key=lambda _, pop: pop))
```

To states under each region with a population less than *100*, you can do:

```
for region, states in regions.items():
    print(region, list(filter(lambda state: state[1] > 100, states)))
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan,

Also under each region, I want to group states with a population less than 100.

How do I go about this pls.?

Comment: Yeaa. It worked fine.Thans again @Ivan.
I wilsharehe project across when am done.
How can I connect with you privately pls?